# Java project archive file submission?

Tags: java, archive

What does it mean to archive all my files into one file? Below are the requirements. I have my program working and stuff, but I don't know why it should be submitted online through an archive file? Does this mean zip? If anyone has experience with this and can inform me. Thank you!

> The files of the problem should be archived into one archive file named BinTree<your 
>      initials>.  The archive file should contain:
>
> 1. UML class diagram (including class relationship) for the main classes
> 2. Commented source code (comments per class and all public methods and instance 
>      variables)
> 3. A short description on what kind of Java codes get generated automatically from the 
>      UML diagram and what you have to add to make the program working.
> 4. API docs produced by javadoc
> 5. A Readme file for those who use linux as the main development platform

Comment: Yes, she probably means zip.

Comment: As nothing special is specified, I'd use the least common archive file you can find, and insist on having done everything as specified. (after all, whoever wrote that text needs a lesson on specification!) BUt if you want to avoid trouble, use `zip`, or, for java `jar`.

Comment: Note that a `jar` file is just a `zip` file with special contents.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally speaking questions regarding the motivations of requirements of teachers are hard to answer here, because they are subjective and, more to the point, don't actually have to do with programming. Be aware this question is likely going to be closed as a result of this not being the ideal forum for it.

Comment: thank you. yes my prof is very foreign and needs help on specification. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic "archive" file terminology simply suggests a way to package all the required components into a single file that you submit. A "zip" file should be fine (there are other formats, "rar" etc.)  You would probably be better off sending a short eMail to your instructor with your assumptions and ask  if they are correct.  ("I assume that a "zip" file with all the components, properly named, will satisfy your submittal requirements? If not, do you have another preference?")

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go with zip over jar (really just the extension is different, but still). Traditionally a `.jar` file is used to pack Java source code for use when deploying an application or library, while `.zip` is used to just keep arbitrary files (like the ones your instructor is requesting) together. It's an extremely common and widely used format that virtually everybody should be able to deal with (Windows has support for it built in, no special software required).

If you are on Windows you can either use a third-party tool (e.g. WinZip) or just put all the files in a folder, right click and choose "Send To -> Compressed Folder" (see [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compress-uncompress-files-zip-files#1TC=windows-7) for Windows 7 instructions, or just Google for it).

On Linux you can use the `zip` tool (or `gzip` for `.gz` files, a very widely used and common option for Linux).

Based on your description, assuming zip files are acceptable and that your real name is Gamer Girl, you'll probably want to name the file `BinTreeGG.zip`.

By the way if I had to guess at the reason she wants this from you, I'd say because it is easier for her to stay organized and deal with submissions from many students when each student only submits a single file (instead of many) with a name that is likely to be unique (your initials).